# Can't login into my netsuite account in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, netsuite

I use the following code in my console application:

```
NetSuiteService service = new NetSuiteService();

Passport passport = new Passport();
passport.account = "TSTDRV976513";
passport.email = "hamzeh.soboh@para-solutions.com";
passport.password = "*******";

RecordRef role = new RecordRef();
role.internalId = "3";
passport.role = role;

Status status = service.login(passport).status;
```

I get the following error:

```
    The request failed with the error message:

    <html><head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
    --
    --
    </html>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quick fix** change the URL to webservices.na1.netsuite.com

**Permanent Fix** http://dreamxtream.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/new-data-centers-for-netsuite-accounts/

Comment: You're right, 'https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2012_1_0/netsuite.wsdl' worked with me... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the URL as above does indeed work, or you could just allow your service proxy to follow redirects and NetSuite will take you to the correct URL automatically:

```
NetSuiteService service = new NetSuiteService();
service.AllowAutoRedirects = true;
```

Seemed to work for me.